# Why is matplotlib plotting nan differently than zeros?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, nan, masked-array

I have 2D numpy array that I want to mask and plot. I have tried this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.random((101,99))

data1 = a.copy()
bound = np.percentile(data1, 80)
data1[data1<bound] = np.nan
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(data1)
```

Output:

[image]

```
data2 = a.copy()
data2[data2 < bound] = 0
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(data2)
```

Output:

[image]

I am expecting the first image to look like the second image, where there are the same number of white pixels as dark-blue pixels, and the white pixels are in the same position as the dark-blue pixels. Clearly, there are more white pixels than dark-blue pixels. I feel like I'm missing something simple. Is something wrong with my `matplotlib` configuration?

EDIT:

To show the first image actually has more white pixels than the second image -- and there are no anti-aliasing effects -- I have rerun the code block using `plt.gca().set_facecolor('black')`:

```
a = np.random.random((101,99))

data1 = a.copy()

bound = np.percentile(data1, 80)
data1[data1<bound] = np.nan
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(data1)
plt.gca().set_facecolor('black')
```

Output:

[image]

```
data2 = a.copy()
data2[data2 < bound] = 0
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(data2)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: NaN values are usually shown fully transparent.  That enables e.g. plotting multiple images with different color maps.  You could try to use `set_bad(..)` on the colormap to change the color for NaNs.

Comment: Ah I must not have been clear. I don't want to change the color of the NaN pixels; I want transparent NaN pixels everywhere there are zeros in the second image. I thought the first code block would do this automatically, but clearly it thinks there are more transparent pixels than there should be (there should be the same number of transparent pixels in the first image as there are zero pixels in the second image).

Comment: I have edited the post with your suggestion, and have to disagree. The differences in the images are not due to lack of contrast.

Comment: I ran your code and the pattern of non NaN points is just the same in both cases.

Comment: Increase the size of your plot (e.g. to (15, 15)) and you'll immediate see the 'missing' pixels. Unless I misunderstood...

Comment: If I understand correctly, your real question is to get your second image, but with white instead of black.  In that case, setting the "under" color to white and drawing using `cmap1 = plt.get_cmap('viridis').copy(); cmap1.set_under('white'); plt.imshow(a, vmin=bound, cmap=cmap1)` could do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect is due to antialiasing. For each pixel on the screen, matplotlib averages out the corresponding pixels of the data. If one of the data pixels is `NaN`, the complete screen pixel is considered transparent. With zeros instead of `NaN`s, the standard averaging is used.

The following code example illustrates what's happening.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.random((101, 99))

data1 = a.copy()
bound = np.percentile(data1, 80)
data1[data1 < bound] = np.nan
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(15, 6))
ax1.imshow(data1)
ax2.imshow(data1)
ax2.set_facecolor('black')

data2 = a.copy()
data2[data2 < bound] = 0
ax3.imshow(data2)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: figsize=(15,6)]

Now, the same, but with `figsize=(10,4)`

[image: figsize=(10,4)]

Comment: Thank you! I clearly don't have a very good grasp of matplotlib functionality. I appreciate your demonstration. @Christian K. had responded with a solution as well, but I have marked yours as the answer as it is more complete.

Comment: Your original question was *"why the difference"*, so that's what my answer tried to show.  Turning off the antialiasing via `interpolation='none')` or `interpolation='nearest')` is also a good way to visualize what's going on. It is a workaround to show more pixels, but also looses smoothness.  If you want to save the result as an image, it helps to increase the dpi.

Comment: Please also see https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_antialiasing.html. Fundamentally if you downsample (your output has fewer pixels than your input) then you need to remove info.  If this is happening you should either increase dpi or use an antialiasing filter

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out this seems to be due to interpolation. On my machine, running your code, there was no difference between the two plots apart from the background. Try to explicitely turn off interpolation:

```
plt.imshow(data1, interpolation='nearest')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your suggestion has worked for me. I have upvoted your reply due to it's simplicity.

Comment: Glad to have helped.